# tmux-powerline status bar works in terminal not in iterm2

Tags: tmux, iterm2

Using the same theme, .tmux-powerlinerc, and .tmux.conf, my tmux-powerline status line works in Apple Terminal, but not in iTerm2. In iTerm2 it doesn't show the left status.

After I first installed tmux-powerline and configured it, the status line was working properly. While editing my copy of the theme file the left status suddenly disappeared and nothing I've tried brings it back.

I backed out all the changes via `git checkout -- <file>` to no avail. I completed removed tmux-powerline and started over thinking it was some configuration change I botched, again with no result.

Both Terminal.app and iTerm2 have UTF8 set for encoding. My .tmux.conf has `set -g ut8` and `set -g status-utf8 on`. I am not using a patched font and therefore have `TMUX_POWERLINE_PATCHED_FONT_IN_USE` set to false.

I have not recently made any changes to iTerm2's preferences.

I'm at a loss as to why the left status suddenly disappeared and how to make it return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by uninstalling iTerm2 and reinstalling it. Removing the com.googlecode.iterm2.plist file didn't help, so I resorted to nuking the entire thing from orbit.

Not sure what got corrupted but I'm pleased a reinstall corrected it.